# Random com.jcraft.jsch.SftpException - No such file or directory with Error code 2

Tags: java, upload, jsch

I have a Java SFTP client app to regularly scan a folder. Once a pair of files(datafile and datafile.md5) exist, the app will upload both files to a SFTP server.

The app is running fine except I am encountering random com.jcraft.jsch.SftpException - No such file or directory exception with Error code 2. I cannot find any common pattern in terms of exception time and exception files. The app will exit after certain retries in logic. However, if I just rerun the app, the uploading will go on smoothly again until next random exception. This happens once a few days.

What else can go wrong and how can I troubleshoot it? I have no clue what can be the root cause. Below is the stacktrace.

```
2020-08-06 02:45:17.890 DEBUG 5708 --- [main] hk.health.common.intf.utils.Logging      : DHCIMS[DEBUG] - SFTP_TRANSFER: Uploading C:/FTP_NFS_SHARE/UAT/immu.dh-ha.sync.20200806024505526.20200806024510090.enc.md5 -> /ARRIVED/immu.dh-ha.sync.20200806024505526.20200806024510090.enc.md5.part total: 90 Bytes
2020-08-06 02:45:17.905  INFO 5708 --- [main] hk.health.common.intf.utils.Logging      : DHCIMS[INFO] - SFTP_TRANSFER: com.jcraft.jsch.SftpException - No such file or directory(ErrorCode: 2)
2020-08-06 02:45:17.905  INFO 5708 --- [main] hk.health.common.intf.utils.Logging      : DHCIMS[INFO] - SFTP_TRANSFER: 2: No such file or directory
        at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.throwStatusError(ChannelSftp.java:2873)
        at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._put(ChannelSftp.java:594)
        at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.put(ChannelSftp.java:475)
        at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.put(ChannelSftp.java:372)
        at hk.health.common.intf.utils.SftpConnection.upload(SftpConnection.java:328)
        at hk.health.common.intf.CimsMigrationSftp100Application.upload(CimsMigrationSftp100Application.java:277)
        at hk.health.common.intf.CimsMigrationSftp100Application.start(CimsMigrationSftp100Application.java:198)
        at hk.health.common.intf.CimsMigrationSftp100Application.run(CimsMigrationSftp100Application.java:111)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:784)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:768)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:322)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
        at hk.health.common.intf.CimsMigrationSftp100Application.main(CimsMigrationSftp100Application.java:106)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52)
```

Below is the code for upload.

```
public int upload (Session session, String sourceFilePath, String sourceFileName, String destFilePath) {
        
        try {
            Channel channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
            channel.connect();
            ChannelSftp sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) channel;
            
            SftpProgressMonitor progressMonitor = new SftpProgressMonitor() {

                @Override
                public void init(int op, java.lang.String src, java.lang.String dest, long max) 
                {
                    logger.WriteLog(log.getPlatform(), "DEBUG", als.getProjectCode(), als.getFunctionId(), als.getTransactionId(), als.getOperationId(), "SFTP_TRANSFER", "Uploading " + src + " -> " + dest + " total: " + max + " Bytes");
                }
                
                @Override
                public boolean count(long bytes)
                {
                    for(int x=0; x < bytes; x++) {
                        //logger.info("#");
                    }
                    return(true);
                }
                
                @Override
                public void end()
                {
                    logger.WriteLog(log.getPlatform(), "DEBUG", als.getProjectCode(), als.getFunctionId(), als.getTransactionId(), als.getOperationId(), "SFTP_TRANSFER", "Upload completed.");
                }
                
                
            };
            
            // Remove remote .part file if exists before upload
            try {
                sftpChannel.rm(destFilePath + sourceFileName + ".part");
                logger.WriteLog(log.getPlatform(), "DEBUG", als.getProjectCode(), als.getFunctionId(), als.getTransactionId(), als.getOperationId(), "SFTP_TRANSFER", "Deleted existing " + destFilePath + sourceFileName + ".part");
            } catch (SftpException e) {
                if(e.id == ChannelSftp.SSH_FX_NO_SUCH_FILE){
                    logger.WriteLog(log.getPlatform(), "DEBUG", als.getProjectCode(), als.getFunctionId(), als.getTransactionId(), als.getOperationId(), "SFTP_TRANSFER", destFilePath + sourceFileName + ".part" + " does not exist");
                } else {
                    logger.WriteLog(log.getPlatform(), "INFO", als.getProjectCode(), als.getFunctionId(), als.getTransactionId(), als.getOperationId(), "SFTP_TRANSFER", e.getClass().getCanonicalName() + " - " + e.getMessage() + "(ErrorCode: " + e.id + ")" );
                }
            }
            
            // Upload
            sftpChannel.put(sourceFilePath + sourceFileName, destFilePath + sourceFileName + ".part", progressMonitor); // Upload file by .put and rename to .part
                        
            // Remove remote data file if exists before rename
            try {
                sftpChannel.rm(destFilePath + sourceFileName);
                logger.WriteLog(log.getPlatform(), "DEBUG", als.getProjectCode(), als.getFunctionId(), als.getTransactionId(), als.getOperationId(), "SFTP_TRANSFER", "Deleted existing " + destFilePath + sourceFileName);
            } catch (SftpException e) {
                if(e.id == ChannelSftp.SSH_FX_NO_SUCH_FILE){
                    logger.WriteLog(log.getPlatform(), "DEBUG", als.getProjectCode(), als.getFunctionId(), als.getTransactionId(), als.getOperationId(), "SFTP_TRANSFER", destFilePath + sourceFileName + " does not exist");
                } else {
                    logger.WriteLog(log.getPlatform(), "INFO", als.getProjectCode(), als.getFunctionId(), als.getTransactionId(), als.getOperationId(), "SFTP_TRANSFER", e.getClass().getCanonicalName() + " - " + e.getMessage() + "(ErrorCode: " + e.id + ")" );
                }
            }
            
            // Rename
            logger.WriteLog(log.getPlatform(), "DEBUG", als.getProjectCode(), als.getFunctionId(), als.getTransactionId(), als.getOperationId(), "SFTP_TRANSFER", "Renaming " + destFilePath + sourceFileName + ".part" + " to " + destFilePath + sourceFileName);
            sftpChannel.rename(destFilePath + sourceFileName + ".part", destFilePath + sourceFileName); // Rename the .part to original file name
            logger.WriteLog(log.getPlatform(), "DEBUG", als.getProjectCode(), als.getFunctionId(), als.getTransactionId(), als.getOperationId(), "SFTP_TRANSFER", "Rename completed.");
            
            if(sftpChannel.isConnected()) { sftpChannel.disconnect(); }
            if(channel.isConnected()) { channel.disconnect(); }
            return 0;
        } catch (JSchException e) {
            // From channel.connect
            logger.WriteLog(log.getPlatform(), "INFO", als.getProjectCode(), als.getFunctionId(), als.getTransactionId(), als.getOperationId(), "SFTP_TRANSFER", e.getClass().getCanonicalName() + " - " + e.getMessage() );
            return 1;
        } catch (SftpException e) {
            // From sftpChannel.put
            logger.WriteLog(log.getPlatform(), "INFO", als.getProjectCode(), als.getFunctionId(), als.getTransactionId(), als.getOperationId(), "SFTP_TRANSFER", e.getClass().getCanonicalName() + " - " + e.getMessage() + "(ErrorCode: " + e.id + ")" );
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();   // Debug random error code(2) - 20200729
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);   // Debug random error code(2) - 20200729
            e.printStackTrace(pw);  // Debug random error code(2) - 20200729
            String sStackTrace = sw.toString(); // Debug random error code(2) - 20200729
            logger.WriteLog(log.getPlatform(), "INFO", als.getProjectCode(), als.getFunctionId(), als.getTransactionId(), als.getOperationId(), "SFTP_TRANSFER", sStackTrace ); // Debug random error code(2) - 20200729
            //e.printStackTrace();  // Debug random error code(2) - 20200729
            return 1;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include all of the relevant code from your application. Ideally you'd post a small self-contained program which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Edited my question to include my codes.

Comment: did you get any solution for this ?